# Is it possible to disable MotionLayout?

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I'v got a `Fragment` that hosts a `RecyclerView` within a `MotionLayout`. On top of the recycler view I've got a view that collapses and expands, all done in my motion scene. It is triggered by a click as well as responding to dragging the recycler view. So far this all works as intended.

Now comes the crux: I'd like to hide the collapsing views completely for some states within my app.
But if I set the views visibility or change its height, it still comes back into view when I drag the recyclerview.

So is it possible to disable the MotionLayout completely (Lock the constraints) until I enable it again. To disable the drag recogniser would also be a viable solution.

Now some simplified XML to demonstrate the situation.

The layout containing the motion layout with header view and recyclerview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/favouritesMotionLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/favourites_motion_scene"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/headerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ...
        />

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        ...
    >

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerVieww
            android:id="@+id/favoritesList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

The corresponding motion scene:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/expanded"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@id/collapsed"
        motion:duration="300">
        <OnSwipe
            motion:touchAnchorId="@id/swipeRefreshLayout"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="top"
            motion:dragDirection="dragUp" />
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/expanded">
        ... Constraints for expanded header ...
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/collapsed">
        ... ... Constraints for collapsed header ...
    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

Using constraint layout version "2.0.0-alpha3"

`implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha3"`

So recap: I'd like to be able to disable the motion layout, so that I can scroll the recyclerview without the header expanding, until I tell it to be enabled again.
Unfortunately it is not as easy as `favouritesMotionLayout.isEnabled = false`, but that is the way I was thinking.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Now with ConstraintLayout beta 2 you can! This is the official way to do it:

`motionLayout.getTransition(R.id.yourTransition).setEnable(false)`

Comment: I am using 2.0.0-beta7 and I can't just run 1 of 2 transitions in motion scene using your snippet

Comment: This is not working on constraintlayout:2.0.4

Comment: Make sure don't forget to set an android:id= to <Transition/>

Answer (score 7):

Actually, i managed to get it working by setting the start state of my scene for both start and end. In kotlin:

```
motionLayout.setTransition(R.id.start, R.id.start)
```

And when i needed to enable my layout:

```
motionLayout.setTransition(R.id.start, R.id.end)
```

No need to change your scene xml, worked flawlessly for me in alpha-03

Comment: lol thanks man. There is an official way to do that with enableTransition() but it is bugged

Answer (score 3):

Recently I've been hacking around MotionLayout a lot, so far I found my trick to disable Motionlayout is like below.

```
layoutContainer.setTransitionListener(object: MotionLayout.TransitionListener {
        override fun onTransitionTrigger(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int, p2: Boolean, p3: Float) {}
        override fun onTransitionStarted(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int, p2: Int) {}
        override fun onTransitionCompleted(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int) {}
        override fun onTransitionChange(p0: MotionLayout?, startedScene: Int, endScene: Int, p3: Float) {
            when(currentFragmentTag) {
                TAG_DEFAULTBACKGROUND ->  {
                    if( startedScene==R.id.halfExpanded ) {
                        layoutContainer.transitionToState(startedScene)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

So basically, I'm telling to MotionLayout to go back on certain situations.
I feel like `onTransitionTrigger` or `onTransitionStarted` should contain the stopping function but it won't listen at those moments.

`onTransitionChange` is where it actually starts moving.
I think you'll get the point of this trick vice versa.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

I found a handy solution to temporarily disable motion layout transtion.
Set this to your MotionLayout in xml :

```
app:interactionEnabled="false"
```

The advantage of the solution is using it directly in an xml file, which gives you the option of connecting to data binding

```
app:interactionEnabled="@{viewModel.shouldInteractionBeActive}"
```

Its working out of box without any additional binding adapters. This was added in  constraintlayout:2.1.0-beta01.

Answer (score 2):

Note that as of the latest beta (beta2), it is possible to disable a transition:
https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/06/constraintlayout-200-beta-2.html

Example usage in Kotlin:

```
(view as? MotionLayout)?.getTransition(R.id.swipe_transition)?.setEnable(false)
```

Comment: It doesn't do anything, am I the only one who is not able to disable a transition doing this?

Comment: Same, can't disable particular transition and run another with that piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4`
and `motionLayout.getTransition(R.id.yourTransition).setEnable(false)` don't work for me, but to fully disable motion layout, for example in my case i need to hide view in special case, but this view involved in animation. So `cardMotionLayout.loadLayoutDescription(0)` fully disable MotionLayout, and to enable again i'm using `cardMotionLayout.loadLayoutDescription(R.xml.fragment_buy_card_step_one_scene)`

Comment: Thanks, my case has been solved already but I am glad you have found another solution as well

Comment: thanks, `motionLayout.getTransition(R.id.yourTransition).setEnable(false)` doesn't work for me either

Answer (score 1):

For me works only next solution.

disable:

```
motionLayout.definedTransitions.forEach {
    it.isEnabled = false
}
```

enable:

```
motionLayout.definedTransitions.forEach {
   it.isEnabled = true       
}
```

Comment: Heey there, thanks for your contribution. I do not have the code and the requirements I needed this for when I asked it, so I cannot easily verify if this would have helped me. But I hope your answer helps someone else. :D

Answer (score 0):

At this point in time it seems it is not possible to disable the motions in a MotionLayout. I hope this will be added in a future version.
To solve my use case I used a bit of a dirty hack: I removed the views making up the header.

`favouritesMotionLayout.removeView(headerView)`

The layout was okay with this and the view disappeared and the motion was not triggered. To get the views back I just reinflated the entire layout. (An alternative would be to add the views again with their constraints programmatically).

I realize this is not the prettiest solution and I am currently looking into ways to solve the entire use case without motion layout. This is unfortunate as it was very useful for up to 90% of my use case.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems there is a way to hack your state to disable the motion transition. It must be added after the transition above in the xml file.
I added another transition with the same start and end state.
In your case:

```
<Transition
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/collapsed"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@id/collapsed"
        motion:duration="0">
```

And in java/kotlin

```
motion_layout.setTransition(R.id.collapsed, R.id.collapsed)
```

Comment: Funny idea, but this will not work dynamically, will it?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
  if (list.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    //disable
                    motionLayout.apply {
                        setTransition(R.id.expanded, R.id.expanded)
                        setTransitionDuration(0)
                    }
                } else {
                   //enable
                    motionLayout.apply {
                        setTransition(R.id.expanded, R.id.collapsed)
                        setTransitionDuration(200)
                    }
                }





 p.s.: 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the transition once the user action is done. Just set the 
 **motionLayout.transitionToState(0)**. You might want to do this in the transition completed callback.

Check if the below code works for you.

```
motionLayout.setTransitionListener(object : 
MotionLayout.TransitionListener {
        override fun onTransitionTrigger(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int, p2: Boolean, p3: Float) {

        }

        override fun onTransitionStarted(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int, p2: Int) {

        }

        override fun onTransitionChange(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Float) {
        }

        override fun onTransitionCompleted(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int) {
            (motionLayout as MotionLayout).transitionToState(0)
        }

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I had to do this and i tried both beta1 & beta2 library and was not able to disable motionlayout and then finally I did this to disable motionlayout animation when my list is empty:-

**SOLUTION**

```
// this fix the transition but other parts of layout will still able to trigger transition somehow to R.id.end!!
motionLayout.setTransition(R.id.start, R.id.start);
// disable all other views touch handling except view clicks.
motionLayout.findViewById(R.id.view_ids).setOnTouchListener(
          (v, event) -> event.getActionMasked() != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
motionLayout.findViewById(R.id.view_ids).setOnTouchListener(
          (v, event) -> event.getActionMasked() != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
     .... disable all the views touch handling cause they can trigger the motion layout animation!

// And then finally has to disable touch handling of motionlayout itself to avoid the space exposed by motionlayout due to padding or margin which can trigger the transition!
motionLayout.setOnTouchListener(
          (v, event) -> event.getActionMasked() != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
```

In short, we need to `setTransition` for start id for both start and end. But I had observed that this is not enough. As somehow `motionlayout` disable the touch handling of `recylerview` but all other parts of `motionlayout` can trigger the transition and so I need to disable all other views' touch handling and let them only handle click events and then finally has to do the same for `motionlayout` too. Cause the space between views handled by motionlayout so when you touch in those parts where motionlayout is, then it will trigger the transition. So need to disable its touch handling too.

**And finally it worked with this solution! Hope this answer help someone! :) enjoy!**

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer by [LPirro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58077083/3485152) was not working for me, I am using beta3 now.
Rather I changed the layoutDescription as per my requirement:

```
public void enableTransition(boolean enable) {
    if (enable) loadLayoutDescription(R.xml.scene);
    else loadLayoutDescription(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible
first

```
motionLayout.getTransition(R.id.yourTransition).setEnable(false)
```

and now replace it with a `Transistion` that dose nothing

```
motionLayout.setTransition(R.id.your_second_Transistion);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to disable the MotionLayout animation-transition is to set the attribute `app:applyMotionScene="false"` on the MotionLayout.

Attribute `applyMotionScene` is format boolean and it is used for enabling/ disabling transition in the MotionLayout.

Comment: That will disable all motion scene. If you just want to disable one transition, this hack won't work.

Answer (score 0):

nothing here worked for me for some reason ...even some caused crashes in android open source..so i created a empty scene and set it like this:

```
binding.myScene.loadLayoutDescription(.R.xml.my_empty_motion_scene)
```

contents of my_empty_motion_scene:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        app:constraintSetEnd="@id/collapsed"
        app:constraintSetStart="@id/expanded" />


</MotionScene>
```

Comment: i was surprised binding.myScene.loadLayoutDescription(0) crashed android. but at least this way seems to work ok.