# How to disable motionLayout transition?

Tags: java, android, android-motionlayout

I have an activity where there is an imageView at the top and a recyclerview at the bottom of the imageview. I used [MotionLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout) to animate the imageView's bottom constraints to top of the screen and recyclerview fill the screen, when I scroll the recyclerview. Everything works fine. But, what I want is that when the recyclerview is empty, I don't want animation to happen. Based on [this](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/06/constraintlayout-200-beta-2.html) document and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58077083/2923116) answer, I used this code:

```
motionLayout.getTransition(R.id.yourTransition).setEnable(false);
```

But, this code is not working for me. Even if I add this code, animation still happens. What is wrong with this code? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

motionLayout.enableTransition(R.id.transition, false)

Comment: This is it! after weeks of trying to disable the motion! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. I had same issue on `constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta3` (downgrade to beta2 didn't help).

I found workaround:

```
motionLayout.setTransition(-1, -1)
```